# Resell a packet of cookies without tampering the packet

Tags: united-states, business, food-processing, food

In the US, Can I simply buy a packet of cookies in a store and resell it without tampering the packet, but simply putting it inside my own branded box to a consumer at a different location in the US.

Points to note:

- I am not tampering the packet
- I am letting the end consumer know who
  actually made it (as I am not tampering packet)
- I am putting the
  packet in my own box
- The value I bring is that I expand the reach of
  that cookie to my audience

What are the laws surrounding it?

Comment: Related: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4429/what-are-the-implications-of-reselling-food

Comment: Thanks, i had read that already. Mine is a case of not tampering the product and letting the end consumer know the original manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that I think you might face is a trademark problem. You can buy and resell stuff as is, but in re-packaging you might face the question of whether Oreos From Khadloya is confusingly similar to Oreos. There is a case (Farouk Systems, Inc. v. Target Corp. Inc., Case No. 06-20883; 2008 U.S. App. LEXIS 1225) where Target boxed hair stuff into a package: it was all labeled properly and one could see what's inside. This was okay. However, Target (the defendant) did have to go to court.

Comment: user6726 is it possible to get in touch with you offline? You can possibly add your bio on your profile.